# Generate unique integer from $n$ integers and solve to get the integers from result

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

What could be the best way to generate a unique integer from $n$ integers in order $(n_1,n_2,\ldots)$?

Further, from $n$, we should be able to get back each $n_1, n_2,\ldots $ etc.
For example, from $n_1=120, n_2=135, n_3=789, n_4=980$, we need a number $n$. And from $n$, we should be able to get back numbers $n_1=120, n_2=135, n_3=789, n_4=980$. For the sake of computation effort, it would be better if we could generate as much small number as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: $2^{n_1}\cdot 3^{n_2}\cdot 5^{n_3}\cdot 7^{n_4}\cdot 11^{n_5}\cdot..$

Comment: The integers $n_i$ are unbounded?

Comment: By "in order" do you mean that $n_i < n_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: I wrote "in order" just to enforce that I may assume n1, n2 etc. as first, second and third so that when computed back from result, I may get the numbers as first, second etc. Otherwise there is no relation between any of the numbers. And yes, the numbers are non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these are nonnegative integers: write $n_1$, $n_2$, $\ldots$, $n_k$ in base $9$, separate with $9$'s, and interpret the result in base $10$.  Thus $120 = 134_9$,
$135 = 160_9$, $789 =1066_9$,  $980 =1308_9$ is encoded as $13491609106691308$.

Comment: Considerable one. But the number when treated as integer is huge. Could there be ways to result in smaller integers?

Comment: It can't be much smaller: you need as many bits of information as you have in the input.

Comment: With 9 inserted, I would need to parse it out as an string. Rather I would prefer 120a135a789a980 which I would then read into a string array by separating with 'a'.

Comment: That would work too (just replace bases $9$ and $10$ by $10$ and $11$, and digit $9$ by digit $a$).